# error in function imshow with created image

Tags: python, image, opencv, imshow

I am working with opencv using python. I have problem with `cv2.imshow()`. I wrote this *code* :

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2  
img=np.zeros((512,512),np.uint8)  
img=cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)  
while(True):  
    cv2.imshow('img',img)  
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):  
       break
```

I get this *error* :

```
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I have tried `cv2.imshow()` without `cv2.line()` it works fine.
how to solve with `cv2.line()` , `cv2.rectanlge()` functions ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking [at the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line):

> Python: cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]]) → None

The return type is `None`, but you assign that to `img`. Just use:

```
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
```

This is the same for all `cv2` functions.

Comment: thnx ken it works fine , "at the docs" would help me a lot also :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `img = cv2.line`.

The line will draw as long as you specify image in the first positional argument.
Do this and see the difference.

```
cv2.line(img, (0, 0), (511, 511), (255, 0, 0), 5)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```